# Pull and run mysql-server docker run using Ansible

Tags: mysql, docker, ansible

I'm trying to pull a mysql-server docker image and run this using my Ansible Playbook.

I have the following task in my playbook:

```
 - name: launch msql-server container
   docker:
    name: db
    image: mssql-server
    ports:
      - 1433: 1433
```

However, this is throwing the error: `This module has been removed.  The module documentation for Ansible-2.3 may contain hints for porting`

I'm not sure why this task is considered pre Ansible-2.3 (I am using Ansible-2.7)

Any help on how to correctly pull the image mssql-server will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ansible` `docker` module is deprecated (ref. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/docker_module.html) and was removed in `ansible v2.4`. You should migrate to using the `docker_container` module (ref. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/docker_container_module.html#docker-container-module) i.e.:

```
- name: launch msql-server container
  docker_container:
    name: db
    image: microsoft/mssql-server
    state: started
    ports:
     - "1433:1433"
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue.

Comment: @fuzzi Great. I had to reject your edits as it's unclear if you're trying to start a Microsoft SQL Server database (`microsoft/mssql-server`) or a MySQL Server database (`mysql/mysql-server`). I assume that it's Microsoft SQL Server on the basis that port `1433` is the default port for MS SQL Server cf. `3306` which is the default port for MySQL Server.